# Match roman numbers using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match `(II|III|IV|V|VI|VII|VIII|ESQ|.JR|.SR)` , if I get a match I should delete it or replace it by a `""`. 
My code is :

```
String fName=" abc III ";
fName = fName.replaceAll("(II|III|IV|V|VI|VII|VIII|ESQ|.JR|.SR)", "");
```

This is working fine for most of the cases but if i give III or VI I get I in my output which I don't want. where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to tell the matcher to be greedy.

Comment: sorry i dint get your comment.

Comment: I know - do some research on regular expressions.  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/Greedy.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
fName = fName.replaceAll("\\s*(III?|I?V|VI{1,3}|ESQ|\\.?[JS]R)\\s*$", "");
```

You need to escape the dot in regex & refactor your regex like shown here.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wH9bX3/2)

Comment: this solution is not matching for SR | JR ,  i am getting SR in my final string.

Comment: for example my input may be abc .JR or abc .SR or abc JR and II ,IIII,IV.. I should get the output as only abc. I should replace II|III|IV|V|VI|VII|VIII|ESQ|.JR|.SR|SR|JR)